# FORM POST not passing input values

Tags: asp.net, forms, internet-explorer, post

I have a simple form that passes to an ASPX page to watch a video. The ASPX page uses a hidden field from the form to load the correct video.

This works for me, but a couple other people are the error message because it appears the value isn't being passed. I'm assuming it's a setting in IE... Anyone seen this or know how to fix? OR a better idea?

Simple form on "yourdomain.org"

> ```
> <form action="http://www.mydomain.org/WatchVideo/Default.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
>     <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="movie.flv" />
>     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Watch Video" />
> </form>
> ```

The ASPX page on "mydomain.org"

> ```
>     If Request.Form("hidden") IsNot Nothing Then
>         lit.Text = Request.Form("hidden")
>     Else
>         Response.Write("Not Authorized. Video Not Passed.")
>     End If
> ```

Sounds and loooks pretty straight forward. Not sure why the same version of IE would have different results. Any other thoughts on how to do this? I need to keep the "off site" coding simple and in HTML for non-technical folks.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe IE can't handle the name 'hidden' for the hidden-field. Have you tried changing it's name? Also, why do you need "enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: i'll try that. I added the enctype when it wasn't working just to try to see if that made a difference.

Comment: changing the name from "hidden" didn't work. it's working and not working on same versions of IE, so it must be a setting?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you add mydomain.org to the trusted sites on the problematic computer - i.e. try ruling out any browser security issues. If you change the form method to GET it should pass the form values as query string arguments... which you can then inspect with the Request.QueryString collection.

Comment: really weird...just tested that in IE9 and it works fine. Make sure you add answer when you find it !

Comment: @Aristos I think Sebastien is just posting the name of the file and the action so his site can then push the content across to the browser from his website.

Comment: I'll update when I figure it out. I would think it has to be a setting since it works on some IE8 and not others. Works fine with my IE9. I'll have to go compare the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a setting inside of the browser. I couldn't narrow it down to a specific setting, but once we changed the "Internet" zone to medium from medium-high it began working. It has something to do with posting form data across domains.